# Consistency of the Speed of Light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

My question is simple and possibly stupid, but I wanted to know hypothetically what would happen if two objects start moving away from each other at half the speed of light (0.5c). Is the observed speeds from within the two objects the speed of light.

And if that is the case what happens when two objects move away from each other at the speed of light, is the observed speed from within the two objects 2c? If so doesn't that exceed the perceived speed of light? Does that also imply then that each light particle is possibly moving away from each other at 2c and not just c.

Also, what does a bystander then observe for the 0.5c experiment. Does he observe 0.5c for each object or does he see the two objects depart at the speed of light.

Could all of this imply that the speed of light is simply relative to the point of observation/measurement. Similar to measuring the position of an electron, which in a sense is everywhere and nowhere at the same time and only appears at the time of measurement. Making it less constant and more of a variable.